Помогите понять код PYTHON
возник вопрос, этот код вычисляет НОД двух чисел(Наибольший общий делитель), не понимаю почему он должен работать корректно, разве цикл не будет работать до тех пока a и b станут нулями*? Разве не надо было написал "or" а не "and"
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
while a != 0 and b != 0:
    if a > b:
        a = a % b
    else:
        b = b % a
gcd = a + b
print(gcd)


Ну представьте, что один уже стал нулем.  Все, на следующей итерации получаем деление на 0 :) Если хоть один стал нулем - значит, второй и есть НОД (деление без остатка).

"пока А не равно 0 И Б не равно 0". Как только одно из них станет равно 0, то условие перестанет выполняться. А вот если написать ИЛИ, то как раз будет выполняться до тех пор, пока обе переменные не станут 0.

Так разве "или" не означает, что для завершения цикла нужно что бы а стал нулем ИЛИ b, то есть одно из них? странная логика у пайтона

Нет, не странная. Это самая обычная математическая логика, которой уже не одна сотня лет. И применяется она во всех языках программирования.

Но вообще то НОД считается циклом проще.

В while указывается условие продолжения работы цикла, а не окончания. Вот если превращать условие в обратное, чтобы прервать по нему цикл, то как известно по арифметике логических операторов, И превратится в ИЛИ:
while True:
    if a == 0 or b == 0: 
        break
    ...

Вот вам как-раз проверка на равенство нулю и использование ИЛИ, всё как вы хотели.

ВОТ ОНО ОБЬЯСНЕНИЕ!!! "В while указывается условие продолжения работы цикла, а не окончания" то есть я думал что она будет работать до тех пор пока a и b не станут нулями, а суть в том что цикл продолжается пока 2 условия соблюдены, спасибо большое!
